# Find Aut$(G)$, Inn$(G)$ and $\dfrac{\text{Aut}(G)}{\text{Inn}(G)}$ for $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find Aut$(G)$, Inn$(G)$ and $\dfrac{\text{Aut}(G)}{\text{Inn}(G)}$ for $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Here is what I have here:

Aut$(G)$ consists of 6 bijective functions, which maps $G$ to itself, since Aut$(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \approx S_3$.

I think the next part goes wrong.  For Inn$(G)$, letting $\kappa_x : G \rightarrow G$ to be the conjugate function, I found $\{e, \kappa_{(0,1)}, \kappa_{(1,0)}, \kappa_{(1,1)}\}$.

I can't determine $\dfrac{\text{Aut}(G)}{\text{Inn}(G)}$ yet since I need to correctly determine Inn$(G)$.

Any advices or comments?

Comment: Something definitely goes wrong, because the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group.

Comment: What do inner automorphism groups do on abelian groups? Just think about how they are defined.

Comment: Use **N/C** lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $G$ is abelian, therefore $Z(G) = G$
($Z$ is the [Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28group_theory%29) of $G$).

Then you can use a little proposition (Humphreys pg.73-74) that tells you $\text{Inn}(G) \approx \frac{G}{\text{Z}(G)}$

The proof of this prop in a few words:

define an automorphism (prove it) $\varphi_x(g)=xgx^{-1}$, then define $\phi : G \to \text{Aut}(G)$ by $x \mapsto \varphi_x$  and find its image and its kernel, then apply first theorem of homomorphism and you conclude.

Comment: In this particular Abelian case, I don't think it takes any proposition to realize that $\phi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}=gg^{-1}x=x$ for every inner automorphism $\phi_g$. Even though the general statement you mention is good to know.

Comment: yes yes, the reason is I was reading the chapters after this in the Humphreys, and I have this prop fresh in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: to expand on Tyler's comment, can you prove that, more generally, $\operatorname{Inn}(G) = \{0\}$ iff $G$ is abelian?

Comment: Oh...  So since $G$ is indeed abelian, Inn$(G)$ is trivial.  What about nonabelian group?  I believe Inn$(G)$ is not trivial, am I right?

Comment: @NasuSama: Did you show that $Aut(Z_2\times Z_2)\cong S_3$?

Comment: Actually, I did.

Comment: @NasuSama in my answer there is the general case about Inn($G$) in a group not necessarily abelian :)